# Probability of infinitely often consecutive successes

Tags: probability, infinity

Hi here is my problem:

> We perform infinitely many independent experiments. The $n^{th}$ one is successful with probability $n^{−α}$ and fails with probability $1 − n^{−α}$, $0 < α$. Let $k ≥ 1$. We are happy if we see $k$ consecutive successes infinitely often. What is the probability of this?

I tried this:

Let $A_i$ be the event "$k$ consecutive successes happen from the $i^{th}$ trial". Then $$\Pr\{A_i\}=\Pr\{\sum_{j=i}^{i+k}X_j=k\}$$ with $X_1,X_2,...$ iid random variables having Bernoulli distribution with parameter $n^{-α}$.

So $$\Pr\{A_i\}=i^{-αk}$$

Then, using Borel-Cantelli Lemmas, we have that $$\sum_{i}^{\infty}i^{-αk}=\infty$$ if $αk<1$ thus $$\Pr\{\bigcap^{\infty}_{j=i}\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}A_i\}=1$$

But I'm sure it's wrong (not coherent) and I don't know where to look for a good way to find the answer...

Thanks,
Herosix

Comment: Isn't it the case that with an infinite number of trials all events which are not impossible will definitely happen (even if they almost never happen)? The more interesting question is the expected waiting time until it happens (ala Shakespeare and monkey-powered typewriters).

Comment: The distribution of $X_i$ depends on $i$. So the probability of $A_i$ does not equal to $i^{-\alpha k}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have done almost all the work, I'll repeat. For the event $A_i$
$$
\Pr\{A_i\}=\Pr\{X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1,\ldots,X_{i+k-1}=1\}=i^{-\alpha}(i+1)^{-\alpha}\cdot\ldots\cdot(i+k-1)^{-\alpha} = \frac{1}{\left[\,i\,(i+1)\ldots(i+k-1)\,\right]^\alpha}
$$
For $\alpha k>1$ the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \Pr\{A_i\}<\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^{-\alpha k}$ converges. By Borel-Cantelli lemma, events $A_i$ occure infinitely often with zero probability.

For $\alpha k\leq 1$ the series diverges. But please note that $A_i$ are not independent. To use second part of Borel-Cantelli lemma, we need in independent events. We can define subsequence of events $B_n=A_{nk+1}$, $n\geq 0$. This events are independent and the event $\{B_n \text{ i.o.}\}$ implies the event $\{A_n \text{ i.o.}\}$ (i.o.=infinitely often).
$$
\Pr\{B_n\}=\frac{1}{\left[\,(nk+1)\,(nk+2)\ldots((n+1)k)\,\right]^{\alpha}}>\left((n+1)k\right)^{\alpha k}
$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr\{B_n\}=\infty$. Then the events $B_n$ occure i.o.  with probability $1$. Then the probability that $A_i$ i.o. is also equals to $1$.